# SQL Server index issue with CPU spiking to 100%

Tags: sql-server

Thanks for you help in advance.

I have a SQL Server which is spiking to 100% CPU for sustained periods.
When I examine long running queries, I can identify the query that is problematic.

The indexes have been established and SQL Server does not suggest any missing indexes when running a plan.

When I rebuild the indexes on the table, my CPU returns to normal levels but returns to 100% CPU within a matter of 10 - 20 minutes.

Rebuilding the indexes once again returns the CPU to normal levels.

What would be causing this? Why would rebuilding the indexes be necessary so soon?

Comment: What I would do first is use `sp_whoisactive @get_plans=1` to check the actual query plan while running. 100% CPU can often mean that you've run out of RAM and it's swapping to disk. To stop running out of RAM, either add more, or optimise your query. What is the biggest wait type on your long running query?

Comment: _SQL does not suggest any missing indexes_ don't pay any attention to those anyway. Missing index suggestions only take the current statement into consideration and are often incorrect anyway. You need to design indexes to be useful for your entire application.

Comment: Thanks Nick.McDermaid, however the query is very simple and is searching by Id and a string so it should not be long running. The issue persists while showing 20% memory usage.
It seems more like the Index is getting corrupted or something.

Comment: This sounds like a parameter sniffing problem. What I'd suggest is grabbing the query plan of the problematic query while you're having the problem, save it off, and then evict it from the plan cache with `dbcc freeproccache(«plan handle for bad query»)`. Then, once you're out of trouble, look at the new query plan generated and compare with the old one. I'd expect the shapes to be different (and using different operators) but pay attention to the compile time parameters.

Comment: @BenThul you were correct! Serve started spiking again and I cleared the plan cache and voila! Thank you so much. If you would like to add it as an answer I can confirm it.

Comment: We're not done yet (or at least I wouldn't be were I you)! What you have now is a less expensive way than rebuilding indexes to return performance to expected levels. Let's see if we can get you to a place where the issue doesn't happen in the first place. When looking at the two plans, what do you notice about the compile time parameters? Is there anything special about those params from a data distribution standpoint for the "bad" plan?

Comment: @BenThul Thanks. Unfortunately, I did not capture them, however the issue happened again today, so I suspect it will again. I will be sure to capture before and after and post it.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks again. I do appreciate your help. The server has not spiked, but I still that this query appears when I test for long running queries. I have posted an image of the query and column schema, here https://s3.us-east-2.wasabisys.com/cdn.proofpix.com/hypenotic/SQLQuery.jpg

Would you mind looking to see if anything stands-out for you? That table does have almost 35 million records.

Comment: Could go a lot of directions on that one. Like, could you add Prefix as a key column into the FileId index so that it doesn't have to use two separate indexes to satisfy the query? Or does it perhaps make sense to cluster that table on FileID (leaving the PK defined as it is)? Or can you make Prefix non-nullable so that LINQ isn't doing the gymnastics of trying to figure out if the column and the parameter are semantically equal? Does the application need literally every column from the table? Et cetera...